# Feedback Topology - MOSFET in feedback network

Tags: amplifier, feedback

i have the following circuit:
[image]
The feedback network consists of M4, which is biased in triode region.

I know the concept behind Feedback Topology and the differences, but I can't figure out why this feedback topology is series-shunt. For me, it seems like a shunt-shunt Feedback (sampled voltage at the output and feedback a current).

Can somebody please explain why it is a series-shunt Topology?

Comment: Indeed the circuit looks like parallel-voltage feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you consider to represent an amplifying subcircuit in your circuit and what node you call the input. If the amplifier is a single M6 transistor, that is, a single stage CS amplifier, and the input to this amplifier is the M1 drain voltage, then the feedback and the input are fed to a common node, the M6 gate, and the topology is shunt-shunt. If the amplifier is two-stage, composed of two CS amplifiers of M1 and M6 transistors with active loads M3 and M6, and the input is Vin fed to the M1 gate, then the feedback and the input enter the amplifier at different nodes, the M6 gate and the M1 gate respectively, and the topology is series-shunt.